# Distance to a closed subspace of a Hilbert space in terms of inner product with the unit normal

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $M$ be a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$, and suppose $x_0\in H$
Show that:

$$\min(\|m-x_0\|, m\in M)=\max(|\langle x_0,n\rangle|, n\in M^\perp ,\|n\|=1)$$

I know that

$|\langle x,y\rangle|^2 \leq \langle x,x\rangle\langle y,y\rangle \implies |\langle x,y\rangle|\leq \sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}\sqrt{\langle y,y\rangle}\implies \|x\| \|y\|$

But I'm not sure where else to go from here...

Comment: Do you know that there exists a unique $m_0\in M$ with $\lVert m_0-x_0\rVert = \min \{ \lVert m-x_0\rVert : m\in M\}$?

Comment: This is not something that was given. Is that statement still true? Part of me wants to say yes (that there $\exists m_0\in M$ which minimizes the Norm.

Comment: Yes, for closed subspaces of Hilbert spaces, that is true. If it's not given, you may not use it without proof or citation, however. If you have the orthogonal decomposition $H = F \oplus F^\perp$ for closed subspaces of a Hilbert space $H$, it follows easily from that [well, the existence of a unique minimiser is usually used to show the existence of the orthogonal decomposition]. Anyway, assuming the existence of the unique $m_0$, can you see some property characterising $m_0 - x_0$ among the $m-x_0$ that might be useful to reach the desired conclusion?

Comment: Would it be the fact that if $m_0\in M$ is the element which minimizes $\|m-x_0\|$ then $(x_0 - m_0)\perp M$?

Comment: Exactly that. $m_0-x_0 \in M^\perp$. Then use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: So one thing I noticed is below. 
Not sure what to do about the min side though... $\max(|\langle x_0,n\rangle|, n\in M^\perp ,\|n\|=1)\leq\max(|\sqrt{\langle x_0,x_0\rangle}\sqrt{\langle n,n\rangle}|, n\in M^\perp ,\|n\|=1)=\max(|\|x_0\|\|n\| |, n\in M^\perp ,\|n\|=1)=\max(|\|x_0\|)=\|x_0\|$

Comment: Note that $\langle x_0,n\rangle = \langle x_0 - m_0,n\rangle$. That is the trick.

Comment: Is that something I would have to prove, or is that something obvious that I am just missing...?

Comment: Obvious (at least after it was pointed out). $m_0 \in M$, and $n\in M^\perp$.

Comment: Ah yeah, that makes sense. So:

$\max(|\langle x_0,n\rangle|, n\in M^\perp ,\|n\|=1) = \max(|\langle x_0,n\rangle - 0|, n\in M^\perp ,\|n\|=1) = \max(|\langle x_0,n\rangle - \langle m_0,n\rangle|, n\in M^\perp ,\|n\|=1) = \max(|\langle x_0-m_0,n\rangle|, n\in M^\perp ,\|n\|=1)$ $\min(\|m-x_0\|, m\in M) = \|m_0-x_0\|$ but I am still not sure how to continue the both sides...

Comment: Any response? To my comment above